# ansible - define var's value depending on another variable

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-2.x

today I have a loop that allows me to start multiple docker containers

```
- name: start container current
      docker_container:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        image: "{{ item.name }}:{{ item.version }}"
        state: started
        recreate: true
        ports:
          - "{{ item.ports }}"
        volumes:
          - /opt/application/i99/{{ item.type }}/logs:/opt/application/i99/{{ item.type }}/logs
        env_file: /opt/application/i99/{{ item.type }}/{{ item.name }}/{{ item.name }}-PreProd-config.list
        env:
            LOG_FILE_WS: "/opt/application/i99/{{ item.type }}/logs/{{ hostname }}_WS.log"
      with_items:       
         - { name: 'backend', ports: '8000:8000', type: 'current', version: '{{RCD_VERSION_CURRENT}}' }
         - { name: 'connecteur', ports: '8400:8400', type: 'current', version: '{{RCD_VERSION_CURRENT}}' }
         - { name: 'api-alerting', ports: '8100:8100', type: 'current', version: '{{RCD_VERSION_CURRENT}}' }
         - { name: 'api-tracking', ports: '8200:8200', type: 'current', version: '{{RCD_VERSION_CURRENT}}' }
```

I have a extra variable  `{{ RCD_APIS }}` that contain a list of all my containers name. I would like to loop over that list and define the following variable conditionnally to the name and run the containers

vars to define : ports, type, version

I want to do something like

```
- name: start container current
      docker_container:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        image: "{{ item }}:{{ version }}"
        state: started
        user: adi99api
        recreate: true
        ports:
          - "{{ ports }}"
        volumes:
          - /opt/application/i99/{{ type }}/logs:/opt/application/i99/{{ type }}/logs
        env_file: /opt/application/i99/{{ type }}/{{ item }}/{{ name }}-PreProd-config.list
        env:
            LOG_FILE_WS: "/opt/application/i99/{{ type }}/logs/{{ hostname }}_WS.log"
    with_items: "{{ RCD_APIS.split(',') }}"
    when: ( item  == "backend", ports: '8000:8000', type: 'current', version: '{{RCD_VERSION_CURRENT}}') or
          ( item  == "connecteur", ports: '8400:8400', type: 'pilote', version: '{{RCD_VERSION_PILOTE}}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# in a vars file, or a `vars` section
---
docker_containers_config:
  backend: 
    ports: '8000:8000'
    type: current
    version: '{{RCD_VERSION_CURRENT}}'
  connecteur:
    ports: '8400:8400'
    type: current
    version: '{{RCD_VERSION_CURRENT}}'
  api-alerting:
    ports: '8100:8100'
    type: 'current'
    version: '{{RCD_VERSION_CURRENT}}'
  api-tracking:
    ports: '8200:8200'
    type: 'current'
    version: '{{RCD_VERSION_CURRENT}}'
```

_

```
# In your tasks
- name: start container current
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    image: "{{ item }}:{{ docker_containers_config[item].version }}"
    state: started
    recreate: true
    ports:
      - "{{ docker_containers_config[item].ports }}"
    volumes:
      - /opt/application/i99/{{ item.type }}/logs:/opt/application/i99/{{ item.type }}/logs
    env_file: /opt/application/i99/{{ docker_containers_config[item].type }}/{{ item }}/{{ item }}-PreProd-config.list
    env:
        LOG_FILE_WS: "/opt/application/i99/{{ docker_containers_config[item].type }}/logs/{{ hostname }}_WS.log"
  with_items: "{{ RCD_APIS.split(',') }}"
```